# Select different pictures in jquery/js

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to make a simple photo viewer, and I want to know how to select the src of that image, in order to change the big image (.big-t)

This is the HTML+JS code part so far:

```
      $("#ImageFound").click(function(e){    
          var bigthumb = $("#ImageFound").attr("src");
          alert(bigthumb);
        });
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="diaporama-thumbs" id="wabi3-slider">
  <div class="thumb-preview">
    <img id="big-thumb" class="big-t" src="big-image1.png" />
  </div>
  <div class="small-thumbs">
    <div class="thumbs-container">
      <div class="small-pre">
        <a id="FindImage" href="#"><img id="ImageFound" src="image1.png"/></a>
      </div>
      <div class="small-pre">
        <a id="FindImage" href="#"><img   id="ImageFound" src="image2.png"/></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The `alert(bigthumb)` only return "image1" even if I click on the second small image

Comment: Your IDs should be unique, to start with. `#ImageFound` exists already. Give the second element another ID.

Comment: But we can't do other way? selecting them automatically without defining a lot of ID's?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(".small-pre img").click(function(e){    
  var smallSrc = $(this).attr("src");
  var bigSrc = "big-"+ smallSrc;

  showPicture(bigSrc);
  
  //alert(bigSrc);
});


function showPicture(src){

  $(".thumb-preview img").attr("src", src)

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="diaporama-thumbs" id="wabi3-slider">
  <div class="thumb-preview">
    <img id="big-thumb" class="big-t" src="big-image1.png" />
  </div>
  <div class="small-thumbs">
    <div class="thumbs-container">
      <div class="small-pre">
        <a href="#"><img src="image1.png"/></a>
      </div>
      <div class="small-pre">
        <a  href="#"><img src="image2.png"/></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</di>
```